# AJAX call not working(jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the JSON data from the openweathermap website.Below is the jquery code that I have written to do so.My goal is to log the JSON data in the console.But console log is showing nothing.I have tried whether success function is working or not by using an alert.But alert dialog is not being displayed.I am not able to figure out where the problem is.Please help me out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submitButton").click(function(){

        //alert("Hello");
        return getWeather();

    });
});

function getWeather(){


    var city=$("#city").val();

    if(city != ''){

        $.ajax({


            url : 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=8eca04841762dd31f99510429e97970a",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success:function(data){

                //alert("hello");
                console.log(data);
                $("#showWeather").html();
            }

        });

    }

    else{


        $("#error").html("<div>City field cannot be empty</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug this in your browser's debugging tools, what is the network response from the AJAX request?

Comment: In addition to the ``success`` callback handler, you could also implement an ``error`` callback handler and log the result.

Comment: @David,It is showing request pending

Comment: Also you can debug your script. You can put breakpoint al line you need

Comment: 'Pending' means that request processing. When you're opening link on browser it's work well?

Comment: @SaiSankalp: So the server never returns a response?  Then the problem isn't in your code.  Maybe you're using this external API incorrectly?  Do you have any working example of how to use this external API?

Comment: @David,yeah I think so.This is the website that is providing the weather API.   http://www.openweathermap.com/current

Comment: @David,Actually I just checked.That API call is also not working in my CHROME browser. I have tried this API call :- http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

Comment: @SaiSankalp I've tested your code [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/du1w2a2f/2/) and it works, check it in local.

Comment: Why did you use 'jsonp'? Response has json format. Use 'json'.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot I have used that in case there will be cross-domain issues.

Comment: Run it on IE if you have CORS.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I am getting request blocked error in the console.

Comment: Your request seems to be failing in when I see it on network. Are you even using the right request?

Comment: Yeah am using the right request. @AakashThakur

Comment: Well, I don't know what's wrong but here is working jsfiddle based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qda4n6nq/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API link using http protocol (not https). So it is possible reason why **[Mixed content error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)** happened.

That's why you can see nothing or notice in some browsers that some insecure content is hidden.

So possible solution is to use http on your site to avoid mixed content. But it is strongly recommended to use https on both servers.

Comment: I have tried out the link which I am using in my API call in my browser.I am doing internship in a company.Its not working when I use that in the computer which is connected to their network.When I am using the same on my phone which is on a different network it is working fine.So any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: You can call API over backend (php file_get_contents) . So in fact it will be API wrapper.

Comment: did'nt quite get you.Can you please elaborate because this is my first time working with API's.

Comment: Ok, you have to write some functionality on the backend (php or something else that you have). This feature must get response from API url that you need. Then you have to get result from your backend request and use those result in a front web page

Comment: Ok will try it.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I had the same problem. What worked for me was use

```
.done(function(data){
        console.log(data)}
```

Instead of

```
success:function(data){
console.log(data);

            }
```